# Deno local import_map not working recursively?

Tags: deno

I have two local deno projects:

```
/Users/thomasreggi/Desktop/utils/
```

and

```
/Users/thomasreggi/Desktop/server/
```

- `server` uses `utils`, they both have import maps
- `utils` works / runs on it's own test pass everything builds

I import `utils` into `server` and now `server` is complaining the import maps I set up in `utils` I now need to add to `server` why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Import maps](https://github.com/WICG/import-maps) are not inheritable (in Deno or elsewhere) — they must be explicitly specified prior to runtime. Part of the reason for this is that their structure is that of an [associative array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array) / object / dictionary — in which each key (specifier in the import map) must be unique.

If a runtime allowed (by some convention) for the automatic detection and merging of import maps, then if/when two duplicate identifiers (keys) were encountered, it would be an unresolvable conflict. The only potential solution would be re-writing of all specifiers in the entire module graph according to some kind of scoping rules (which aren't nearly as simple as it sounds).

If you are sure that your dependencies use exclusive identifiers in their import maps (or that the resolved values at the duplicate specifiers are identical), then you could write a build/pre-run [task](https://deno.land/manual/tools/task_runner#task-runner) that generates an import map for your project prior to using it in the `deno run` command.

Comment: This is great, I'd love to build tooling the around this to replace the source itself to switch back and forth between using the key in the import map, and or switch to use the urls.